# ComboBox is always fixed size regardless of Width settings in Xamarin WinPhone

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.winphone

I have the following template:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ListViewItemTemplate">
            <Grid x:Name="grid">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                           Margin="5"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           FontSize="18"
                           Foreground="Black"
                           Text="{Binding Text}"
                           TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" />
                <my:CustomControl Grid.Column="1"
                    ActualValue="{Binding Val, Mode=TwoWay}" />

                <ComboBox x:Name="cboxPicker"
                          Grid.Column="2"
                          Width="70"
                          MaxWidth="70"
                          MinWidth="70"
                          Margin="3"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          ItemsSource="{StaticResource dataSource}"
                          SelectedIndex="{Binding Val, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                 <Border Grid.Row="1"
                         Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                         BorderBrush="Gray"
                         BorderThickness="1" />
   </Grid>
 </DataTemplate>
```

If I add a `Width`, `MinWidth` or `MaxWidth` properties, it cuts the ComboBox in half.

[image]

If I don't set any of it, the ComboBox has the Width ***around 100-110***, it is too large.

[image]

How can I set it to a proper and exact size?

Comment: Try to override resource `<x:Double x:Key="ComboBoxPopupThemeMinWidth">80</x:Double>` - make it lower.

Comment: @crea7or I guess it is the popup that this "setting" is for, not the base item. Also, I don't know how to use this double inside my control. Can you provide a full style?

Comment: Yes, it's for popup. I don't know much about xamarin, but this style should be set in app.xaml. Do you have it in xamarin?

Comment: @crea7or This is native Windows Phone 8.1 code, I use it in a Template. I don't get how it should be used. I've seen `<Style x:Key="MyStyle">` but never seen a built-in variable type used with a key. Should I put it in App.xaml as it is?

Comment: This style should be overwritten in app.xaml (change value to 60 or less).  You can check other values by this link, but please note - this is windows 10 version and control template is a bit different in 8.1: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299116.aspx

Comment: @crea7or I could find another key but it has no effect  in Windows Phone 8.1: `ComboBoxThemeMinWidth`. Also, I couldn't find any suitable property to override here: https://gist.github.com/longzheng/2308859 It seems, that the ComboBox has to be this large...

Comment: Find `ComboBox` template by your link  ( starts with `<Style TargetType="ComboBox">`) and you'll find `ComboBoxPopupThemeMinWidth` in the `ScrollViewer` `MinWidth`.

Comment: @crea7or That key is not working, either. It disregards both `ComboBoxPopupThemeMinWidth` and `ComboBoxThemeMinWidth`. I really don't understand, why it is so hard to achieve.

Comment: Try to modify the whole style of control. Create copy of `ComboBox` style and play with width of elements inside.